# Java code obfuscating, get orginal class name

Tags: java, class, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I'm developing a application in JAVA that needs to register some class names in the Database at runtime.

The problem is that when we deploy the application it's build with some code obfuscater (I think it is called ProGuard), that renames the class names for securing the .Jar files.

I haven't worked before with a code obfuscater and i believe that the output of the obfuscated class name can differ per package for the same class. So this is a problem for me.

Example obfuscated class name;

```
//method of retrieving class name:
objMyClass.getClass(); //output: 'MyPackage.MyClass'

//result building obfuscater enabled:
objMyClass.getClass(); //obfuscated output: 'X.B'
```

So my question is:

Is there a way to programmatical resolve/translate (without Vulcan powers :) ) the original class name when the code is obfuscated? I have the original (non-obfuscated) .Jar/.Java files, Or is there a different way to identify the original Class Type  of a given object at runtime?

Thanks!

Jelte.

Comment: What's your goal?  If you've already got non-obfuscated java and jar files, is this just to see how thorough obfuscation is?

Comment: I see it in your question now, sorry I missed it.  It looks like class.ForName() will still work, according to ProGuard:  http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#FAQ.html

Comment: Every obfuscator I've seen allows one to specify certain class names that should be left unobfuscated.

Comment: @Gus: The given object type (class name) is dynamic, so i dont have a some kind of 'fixed' list, I need to identify a Object by its original classname on the fly at runtime because when obfuscated, the classname can be obfuscated/called differently in a other package. No this is not for experimental purposes ;)

Comment: If the class name is obfuscated, what good does knowing the original class name do you???

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how the code is obfuscated, it is impossible to get the original class name at run time. The point of a obfuscator is to make code ambiguous, but still functional. You would need a way to programatically unobfuscate it at run-time.

Comment: Well, it is possible to do it -- just define a static var in the class:  `static String originalClassName = "TheOriginalClassName";`.

Comment: Ha, I guess you are right. I feel this may defeat much of the purpose of obfuscation though.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make much sense to even want the original name of an obfuscated class name, since there's not really anything you can do with it other than to log it.